# Reading file using webhdfs

Tags: hadoop, curl, hdfs, webhdfs

I'm reading file residing on HDFS using curl(webhdfs) but problem is with data I'm getting HTTP headers also , How can I get only file data withought headers ?

I'm using below command. If I'm removing "i"' option no output is given

```
curl i -L --negotiate -u: -X GET "http://hostname:port/webhdfs/v1/user/TRL.TXT?op=OPEN"
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Look like there is typo in your question(I think `i` should be `-i`). If you are using `-i` option for `curl`, it will dump headers also. To get file without headers do not use `-i` option

To get file **with** headers:

`curl -i -L --negotiate -u: -X GET "http://myserver.example.com/myweb/a.html"`

To get file **without** headers:

`curl -L --negotiate -u: -X GET "http://myserver.example.com/myweb/a.html"`